# does a computer use RAM to shut down

Tags: shutdown

Just out of curiosity, does a Windows 7 computer use RAM when it shuts down, and is there an executable for the shut down process? If so, does that mean a computer can't shut down if its RAM is maxed out?

Comment: No; it doesn't..

Comment: "Shut down" is a broad term.  If you have a running, say, Windows box and you tell it to shut down, it will in turn tell all running applications to shut down.  Those apps may need more storage to accomplish their shut down operations.  After that, the OS needs to do some housekeeping, to save status.  This may require small amounts of additional RAM.

Comment: To answer your second question, C:/Windows/System32/shutdown.exe is called everytime the shutdown request is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only RAM shutting down your computer uses is to run shutdown.exe in C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe. Unless Windows is performing updates, it would only use around 40kb of RAM to initiate shutdown.

Comment: Windows doesn't call shutdown.exe to shutdown the computer.  In the other way round, shutdown.exe provides only an interface to signal Windows to shut down.

Comment: @KennethL Wrong. Explain this then: If you go in Task Manager and press "Show processes from all users" and then shut down the PC, shutdown.exe appears there while the computer is shutting down. That's how I found out about this, I was monitoring apps that launch when shutdown is called.

Comment: shutdown.exe is simply a wrapper for `InitiateSystemShutdownEx()` that signals Windows to shutdown. In earlier versions of Windows (e.g. Windows 2000 which use similar NT architecture) there is no shutdown.exe coming with the system. [Further reading](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-shutdown-process.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly normal for a computer's RAM to be maxed out. RAM does not need to be free to be used. Modern operating systems can directly transition RAM from one use to another. So there's no problem with allocating RAM for important purposes even if all RAM is currently in use.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad; the answer depends on the operating system and the shutdown process.  For example, on a UNIX system you can take a system down to single user mode by sending a terminate signal to process 1, which can be done from an existing root shell without allocating more memory.  Upon receipt of the signal process 1 will send terminate signals to all the other processes on the system and then launch a single user shell.

If you want a more orderly shutdown of the system, you can run /sbin/shutdown, which can send messages to users on the system warning of the impending shutdown.  But running /sbin/shutdown means launching a new process, and that will involve allocating RAM.

Comment: That may or may not be possible without allocating memory. If, for example, the process has been paged to disk, physical memory will have to be allocated to page in the executable before it can respond to the signal.